# Visual Studio Format Document inserts tab after data-bind

Tags: visual-studio, data-binding, knockout.js, tabs

cshtml files with more than one data-bind on a line get a tab (four spaces) insterted after the >data-bind="<. This happens when Visual Studio does "Format Document". And is therefore reproducible by Edit->Format Document.

Only the additional data-binds have this, so the 2nd and 3rd get spaces added while the first remains normal:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: Active" /><span data-bind="text: firstName"></span><span data-bind="text: lastName"></span>
```

Changes into:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: Active" /><span data-bind="    text: firstName"></span><span data-bind="    text: lastName"></span>
```

It's not a huge problem, stuff can be placed on seperate lines, but still annoying.

Edit: Since vs2013 I no longer have this problem. That also seems to have fixed another problem where vs would randomly decide to move my carret and type some spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I am working with Visual studio 2012, and I don't facing this problem.
May be you could try to reset your VS settings.
If it doesn't work, I will post my settings.

Comment: I tried installing Resharper, resetting my settings no improvement. My collegues don't have this problem.

Comment: @MrFox any updates on this?  It happens to me all the time and it's infuriating.

Comment: @SB2055 vs2013 seems to fix the problems, made an edit in the question.